# Scroll content in UITextView with limited lines count

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've problem with setting UITextView control to work as I expect.
I have something like that:

```
[textView.textContainer setMaximumNumberOfLines:3];
[tv.textContainer setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

My expected result is to have editable text view with default 1 line height. When I put text, the control expend to 3 lines maximum, and after that I still be able to write, but content will be scrollable in 3 lines control.

Unfortunately based on above code I'm not able to get this result. When my control has 3 lines height, and I put more text, then my cursor disappear and I still can write, but without possibility to scroll entered content.

Do you have any advices or hints how can I achieve expected behavior of UITextViewController?

Comment: How are you setting the frame (e.g. Interface Builder or Auto Layout constraints in code...) of the textView? It's the size of the textView that will dictate when the scrolling starts... If all you're doing is restricting the number of lines to 3... The textView is probably still quite big. Try setting the background colour of the textView to red (or something) to see what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, here's an example of how you can control how much 'space' a `UITextView` can use and how the scrolling is set up to match:

```
UITextView* _textView = [UITextView new];
// other setup...
_textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 5, 8, 5);
_textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(52, 0, 0, 0);
```

In this example, I had the `_textView` taking up all of it's parent view (using auto layout constraints, which amounted to the whole screen). E.g.

```
NSArray* constraints;
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_textView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_textView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

I also had a custom toolbar at the top of the screen, which had a height of `52`. (Custom toolbar, not the stock `UINavigationBar`).

So, in this case I used the `textContainerInset` property to restrict the portion of the text view that would be used for displaying text: the top margin is most relevant, I wanted to clear the height of `52` from the toolbar and then have some additional *margin* (8).

Additionally, I used the `scrollIndicatorInsets` to make the scroll indicators stop `52` units from the top (the size of the toolbar).

I don't know exactly how your `textView` fits with the other controls in your view... but, to control the amount of space used for text and how the scrolling works along with that, you need to do more than:

```
[textView.textContainer setMaximumNumberOfLines:3];
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Gavin. Thanks for the wide explanation. To be more precisely I try to achieve expected result in input filed in http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/6.0.0/index.html By default this input text view (new message) is expandable without any limit. In my code I have access to it, so I try to set my limit and add scroll functionality to this input bar.

Comment: Just to check, you're using the `inputAccessoryView property` as the view that has the `UITextView` you're using to enter the text?

Comment: However you're doing it... just try restricting the height of the text view, so that it can't grow 'taller' than a value that's suitable for 3 lines of text... then the scrolling will kick in. And you shouldn't need to set the maximum number of lines...